# Flask raises jinja2.exceptions.templatenotfound error

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to render the file bootstrap.html. The file exists in my folder, but I keep getting jinja2.exceptions.templateNotFound: bootstrap.html when I try to render it. Why can't Flask find my template?

````
@app.route("/bootstrap")
def bootstrap ():
    return render_template('bootstrap.html')```
````

Answer (score 1):

Flask by default is looking for a folder named tempates
This is a suggested simple file structure for you project

```
    app.py
    config.py
    requirements.txt
    static/
    templates/
```